# NodeJS JSON Array filtering

Tags: sql, arrays, json, node.js, filter

I have used Node to retrieve a set of results from SQL and they're returned like this;

```
[
   {
   "event_id": 111111,
   "date_time": "2012-11-16T01:59:07.000Z",
   "agent_addr": "127.0.0.1",
   "priority": 6,
   "message": "aaaaaaaaa",
   "up_time": 9015040,
   "hostname": "bbbbbbb",
   "context": "ccccccc"
},
   {
   "event_id": 111112,
   "date_time": "2012-11-16T01:59:07.000Z",
   "agent_addr": "127.0.0.1",
   "priority": 6,
   "message": "aaaaaaaaa",
   "up_time": 9015040,
   "hostname": "bbbbbbb",
   "context": "ddddddd"
},
]
```

There are usually a lot of entries in the array and I need to efficiently filter the array to show only the entries that have a context of "ccccccc". I've tried a for loop, but it's incredibly slow.

Any suggesstions?

Comment: Why can't you constrain your query to only return `cccccccc` contexts?

Answer (score 9):

There is a very simple way of doing that if you want to do that in node and don't want to use sql for that you can user javascript built-in Array.filter function.

```
var output = arr.filter(function(x){return x.context=="ccccccc"}); //arr here is you result array
```

The ouput array will contains only objects having context "ccccccc".

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing what Khurrum said, is with the arrow function.  It has the same result but some people prefer that notation.

```
var output = arr.filter(x => x.context == "ccccccc" );
```

Answer (score 0):

1. As suggested by Matt, why not include `WHERE context = "ccccccc"` in yout SQL query?
2. Else if you must keep all in maybe use one of the following to filter the results

   ```
   // Place all "ccccccc" context row in an array

   var ccccccc = [];

   for (var i = results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     if(results[i] == 'ccccccc')
       ccccccc.push(results[i]);
   };

   // Place any context in an named array within an object

   var contexts = {};
   for (var i = results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

     if(contexts[results[i]] == 'undefined')
       contexts[results[i]]

       contexts[results[i]].push(results[i]);
   };
   ```

   or use the [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) (or similar) [filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) function.

Comment: There is native V8 `Array.filter` (I believe underscore will use that anyway).